# Resolving a git rebase issue

Tags: git

Coworker has checked-in his changes to the branch we both work on.
I first did a `git add and git commit` and then I did a `git pull --rebase`
which said there are some conflicts, So I opened a text editor and resolved those conflicts and again I did a `git add .  and git commit` and then a `git rebase --continue`

But at this point I get this message, if I say git rebase --continue again I get the same message. Stuck on this, what is the next step I should do ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your mistake was running `git commit` after resolving the rebase.

When you encounter a conflict, you should do the following:

1. resolve the conflict
2. stage the files (`git add ...`)
3. continue the rebase. (`git rebase --continue`)

There's no need to commit between steps 2 and 3.